# File operation in RxJava causes leak of file descriptor in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, okhttp

I develop android app and I want to download many files(about 1000 files).

it's with Okhttp and RxJava, and it in service.
but app must crashes by leak of file descriptor in loop about 200th:

```
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    Observable.fromArray(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]))//url list
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(url -> {
                Response response = request(url, null);
                String lastSegment = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), lastSegment);
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(response.body().bytes());
                fos.close();
                response.close();
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(url -> onProgress(stateCode, count.incrementAndGet(), list.size()),
                    this::handleError, this::onCompleteDl);
```

and error log:

```
06-15 06:26:52.204 22654-24804/{MY_PACKAEGENAME} A/libc: FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
06-15 06:26:52.634 25745-25745/? A/google-breakpad: Microdump skipped (uninteresting)
06-15 06:26:52.794 22654-24804/{MY_PACKAEGENAME} A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24804 (RxCachedThreadS)
06-15 06:26:52.854 18430-18430/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/SC-04F/SC-04F:6.0.1/MMB29M/SC04FOMU1XQH1:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '13'
    ABI: 'arm'
    pid: 22654, tid: 24804, name: RxCachedThreadS  >>> com.cks.hiroyuki2.radiko <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
06-15 06:26:53.024 18430-18430/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE'
        r0 00000000  r1 000060e4  r2 00000006  r3 87b03978
        r4 87b03980  r5 87b03930  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
        r8 87afa6e4  r9 87afa778  sl 0000000a  fp 00000002
        ip 00000006  sp 87afa630  lr b6c8fc31  pc b6c92020  cpsr 40010010
06-15 06:26:53.044 18430-18430/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00042020  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
        #01 pc 0003fc2d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
        #02 pc 0001c3b3  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
        #03 pc 00019631  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
        #04 pc 00017584  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
        #05 pc 0001afc7  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16)
        #06 pc 0001afdf  /system/lib/libc.so (__fortify_chk_fail+18)
        #07 pc 00045d85  /system/lib/libc.so (__FD_SET_chk+24)
        #08 pc 0000a4cf  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
        #09 pc 0000b0ab  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
        #10 pc 033ec46f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x2f3a000)
06-15 06:27:00.724 18430-18430/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
```

I'm new to RxJava, so I think It's wrong to use RxJava.
How can I solve it? What's the wrong point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which API version of android you are debugging on?

Comment: One major flaw in your code is that you aren't catching IOExceptions.  You should be doing that inside your doOnNext and closing streams/files properly.  Your code there currently has no error handling-  I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: the android version is 6.0.1(API 23), and it's physical.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan In my addition, error hander automatically emits when exception thrown. Is it wrong?